# How do I get lombok to work with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code, lombok

I have a java gradle project in vscode, and I followed the instructions on the site to use the gradle plugin and the vscode lombok extension. However, vscode is still unable to resolve the lombok.Data java import. What am I missing?

Comment: Which instructions you followed, can you provide the link? Also when mentioning the plugins please provide the links. Did you include the *Lombok* dependency to your `pom.xml` file ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out I had to run the following command in VS Code:

```
> Java: Clean the Java language server workspace
```

Comment: Command Palette, on mac one can launch the wizard by opening the Command Palette (⇧⌘P) and typing the command above.

Answer (score 9):

Use next plugin [Lombok Annotations Support for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GabrielBB.vscode-lombok)

Comment: That's the plugin that I'm using

Answer (score 0):

Try to exclude transitive dependency for better control

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I am using VScode editor try to add lombok for from the extension window. After that clean the workspace it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As of Dec. 2022, according to this announcement https://devblogs.microsoft.com/java/java-on-visual-studio-code-update-december-2022/ , quote: "Starting in July, our Java extensions can directly support projects that are using Lombok without installing any additional extensions."

Of course, lombok must be in your classpath, either as a jar or part of a build tool configuration like maven or gradle.

Setup:

- maven: https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven
- gradle: https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle

It must be enabled in settings though. I'm not sure if it is by default. This screenshot shows how to enable.

[image: Settings for enabling lombok]